Why doesn't my map load properly at certain times? (SwiftUI)
I'm having a problem loading the map. Here's a gif showing the problem, it's once in a while, not every time. :

Normally, the case that should work is as shown in the image below :

Here is the View code and the ViewModel code :
struct Map4View: View {
    
    @StateObject var mapViewModel:Map4ViewModel = Map4ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Map() {
            ForEach(mapViewModel.pointsMission.filter { pointsMission in pointsMission.isCurrent}) { currentPoint in
                Annotation("\(currentPoint.latitude), \(currentPoint.longitude)", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentPoint.latitude, longitude: currentPoint.longitude)) {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).fill(.white)
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(Color.init(hex: "8aa873"))
                        Image(systemName: "ant.fill").padding(5).foregroundStyle(Color.init(hex: "8aa873"))
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if let route = mapViewModel.currentRoute{
                MapPolyline(route.polyline)
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
            }
        }
        .mapStyle(.hybrid(elevation: .realistic)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: { mapViewModel.validateMosquitoRelease() }) {
                    Text("Valider la libération des moustiques")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }.disabled(mapViewModel.isButtonVisible).padding()
                Spacer()
            }.background(.white.opacity(0.8))
            
        }.onAppear {
            Task { await mapViewModel.getPointsMission() }
        }
    }
}

 func getPointsMission() async {
        pointsMission = [
            PointsMission(latitude: 45.8342019, longitude: 1.2537218 ),
            PointsMission(latitude: 45.8343859, longitude: 1.2521066 ),
            PointsMission(latitude: 45.8356658, longitude: 1.2526660 ),
            etc...
        ]
        
        pointsMission[currentIndex].isCurrent = true;
        
        createRoute(
            start: locationManager.location?.coordinate,
            end: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: pointsMission[currentIndex].latitude, longitude: pointsMission[currentIndex].longitude)
        )
    }

If you can help me, I'm already 2 days into my search... Thank you ;)

Note, you should use .task{ await mapViewModel.getPointsMission() }
instead of .onAppear{...}.
